# extracting cell values in open office calc to set variables in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, openoffice-calc

Im intrested in finding out how i can add and extract cell values in open office calc using VB.net

dose anybody know any good refrences online to help me get started

Comment: is it even posible might be a good starting question

Answer (score 0):

The first think you need is the OpenOffice SDK. Here is that link: http://download.openoffice.org/other.html#tested-sdk

Now, most of the examples are written in JAVA and C++. However, there are several sites out there that have utilities or example code for porting to VB.NET. However, you should really learn about UNO with Open Office through this link here: http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/OpenOffice.org_Developers_Guide.

Use the guide in tandem with any control or interface you use so that you have a clear understanding of what you are attempting to do. Here is an thread from another site that shows some example code: http://user.services.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=25&t=15504

Comment: Perhaps a stuipid question but cant i just treat the programming the same as with excel if i svae my CALC file as an xls extention?

Comment: Not a stupid question. Yes, if you wanted to avoid the UNO environment, then saving as an Excel Workbook would allow you to integrate Office Interop through .NET